# How to handle queries with multiple words in custom search engine

Tags: java, search-engine, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>` which contains a word and list of occurrences. A value at position `i` will indicate that many occurrences of that word in `ith` document.

I have handled the part in which user searches for one word. But in case of multiple words, I need some help in implementing it. If user searches for `Star` then the program will return URL of the page with most number of occurrences using `maxheap`. But if user searches for `sun and star`, how can I handle this?